# Resolving path in systemjs-builder

Tags: angular, systemjs

My project structure is something like this:

```
/node_modules

/client
|---/app
|   |---/app.module.ts
|   |---/main.ts
|---/systemjs.config.js
|---/index.html

/server
|---/server.js

/tools
|---/builder.js

/package.json
```

I'm using angular2-rc5
And I have exposed some directories with express server and mapped them to following routes:

```
/client         =>    /
/node_modules   =>    /
```

So, when a user visits '/' from the browser he get's the `/client/index.html` file.

On `index.html` the `baseUrl` is set like this:

```
<base href="/">
```

The systemjs is imported like this:

```
<script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
<script>
  System.import('app');
</script>
```

On `systemjs.config.js` the app is mapped like this:

```
var map = {
  'app': 'app',
  '@angular': '@angular'
}
```

Now I'm trying to bundle my app with systemjs-builder and the script `builder.js` is like this:

```
var SystemBuilder = require('systemjs-builder');
var builder = new SystemBuilder();

builder.loadConfig('client/systemjs.config.js')
    .then(function(){
        var outputFile = './client/assets/js/bundle.min.js';
        return builder.buildStatic('app', outputFile, {
            minify: true,
            mangle: false,
            rollup: true
        });
    })
    .then(function() {
        console.log('bundle built successfully!');
    });
```

Now the problem is, the routes in my server is not the same as my project structure. So, when I specify 'app' in the `builder.js` it actually tries to find `/app` and not `/client/app`

One work around was to setup two different maps in the `systemjs.config` for browser and non-browser operation like this:

```
var isPublic = typeof window != "undefined";
var map = {
  'app': 'app',
  '@angular': (isPublic)? '@angular':'../node_modules/@angular'
}
```

But since my baseURL is set to `/client` I can't really map to `node_modules/@angular`; I've to go a directory up and the locate it(i.e `../node_modules/@angular`). But doing this, shows me:

`Error: Unable to calculate canonical name to bundle file:///usr/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic//bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js. Ensure that this module sits within the baseURL or a wildcard path config.`

I wan't `node_modules` and `client` to be routed to `/` so that my end-user can't see the actual path.

**Now, How can I bundle this application with systemjs-builder?**

Answer (score 0):

That error says:

> Ensure that this module sits within the baseURL or a wildcard path
>   config.

Clearly node_modules can't be within the baseURL, so you can try the second approach for the builder config and add `paths` instead of changing `map`:

```
paths: {
    '@angular/': '../node_modules/@angular/'
}
```

BTW the wording in that message will be out of date shortly, [wildcards in paths config are being deprecated](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/issues/1039), nowadays one should use trailing slashes there so `'path/'` is the preferred way over `'path*'`.